# How to store array of objects in a cookies with Next JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, next.js

in my Next app I'm getting an object using context API and routing to a page. in the destination page I'm storing that data with use State.

```
const { contents } = useContext(PageContext);
const [result, setResult] = useState([]);
```

but the state doesn't persist on page reload. so My approach was to store it in a local storage.

```
useEffect(()=>{
    if( contents !== null) {
      localStorage.setItem('content', JSON.stringify(contents))
      setResult(contents)
    }
  },[])

useEffect (()=>{
    if ( contents === null){
      const resultStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('content')) || "[]"
    setResult(resultStorage)
    }
   },[result])
```

and of course this fails. b/c I'm using `getStaticProps` in my `index.js` to fetch a playlist from YouTube API. and it prompts an error `referenceError: localStorage is not defined`, so I tried to store these results is Cookies.

```
useEffect(()=>{
    if( contents !== null) {
      Cookies.set('content', JSON.stringify(contents))
      setResult(contents)
    }
  },[])

useEffect (()=>{
    if ( contents === null){
      const cook = JSON.parse(Cookie.get('content')) || "[]"
    setResult(cook)
    }
   },[result])
```

for the cookie I used the package `Cookie-cutter` `import Cookie from 'Cookie-cutter'`. and these cookie value is stored as `%5Bobject%20Object%5D`.

what I want to do in my app is to display detail page for a selected card. so what is the fix?

Comment: _"it prompts an error `referenceError: localStorage is not defined`"_ - Can you clarify what prompts this error? The code you showed would not trigger that error, since you're accessing `localStorage` inside `useEffect` which always runs on the client-side. Are you trying to access `localStorage` somewhere else?

Comment: @juliomalves no but when I pass from the source page instead of passing from destination to set and get, it worked.